# Toggle between displaymath and inline math modes in LaTeX

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I'm trying to come up with a way of doing the following in vim. When editing LaTeX documents, I need on a fairly regular basis to toggle between display and inline math modes. Let me explain: suppose I'm wrtting

```latex
Consequently, one gets a function $\Omega^2 \mathbb S^2 \to \Omega \mathbb S^1$
```

And I realize that it is not visually appealing to put the math inline, so I want to get:

```latex
Consequently, one gets a function 
\begin{displaymath} 
  \Omega^2 \mathbb S^2 \to \Omega \mathbb S^1
\end{displaymath}
```

Ideally, I want to get that result by just a few keystrokes when the cursor is inside the equation, and I would like to get the converse transformation by the same command: the command should then detect first if I'm in inline or display mode and then perform the necessary transformation.

I fear to dive in a regexp-hell when there might be a simpler way. Note that I'm fairly new to vim, so the answer might be completely obvious. I'm only using vim-latex as a plugin and I would prefer if there is a *vanilla vim* way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a not so elegant solution I created based on my non existent knowledge of latex.

The idea is to create a mapping (replace `gs` by whatever you prefer) which calls a function which does all the work.

The function checks if the current line has a string surrounded by `$` signs (I assumed that's how you delimit your inline expression). If such a string exists we get it in a variable `l`, remove the `$`s, remove the string from the line, add the `\begin` and `\end` markers and the expression we got before, and use `=` to reindent everything.

If the string wasn't found then we do the opposite: find the delimiters, remove them, join the lines between them, add the surrounding `$` and join with the previous line.

**Warning** I did this quickly because I thought it was fun but I know nothing about LaTeX and there are probably a lot of edge cases I didn't think about. For example if you use the mapping on a line which is neither a block expression or an inline expression you will completely mess up your buffer.

From my tests this solution works on your example but that's all I can say. Also I suspect that in a few hours one of the Vim Gurus we have on this site will come up with an elegant solution of just a few lines... we'll see :)

```
nnoremap gs :call ToggleLatexMathMode()<CR>

function! ToggleLatexMathMode()
    " Get the current line and check if we find an expression surrounded by $ signs
    let l=getline('.')
    let inline=match(l, '\$[^$]\+\$')

    " Inline to block
    if (inline >= 0)
        " Get the expression
        let l=matchstr(l, '\$[^$]\+\$')
        " Remove the surrounding $ signs
        let expr=substitute(l, '\$', '', 'g')
        " Remove the expression from the line
        execute 's/\%' . inline  . 'c.\{' . ( len(l)+1 ) . '}//'
        " Append the delimitors and the expression without $ signs
        call append(line('.'), '\end{displaymath}')
        call append(line('.'), expr)
        call append(line('.'), '\begin{displaymath}')
        " Format to get the right indentation
        normal! =}
    " Block to inline
    else
        " Get the lines delimiting the expression
        let start=search('begin{displaymath}', 'b')
        let end=search('end{displaymath}')
        " Delete the surrounding lines
        execute(end . 'd')
        execute(start . 'd')
        " Join the lines in the expression
        execute(start . ',' . (end-2) . 'join')
        " Add the surrounding dollar signs
        call setline(start, substitute(getline(start), '^\s*', '$', '') . '$')
        " Join with the previous line
        normal! kJ
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks for the piece of code. It is not exactly what I'm after (for example, it will always toggle the first piece of math between $$ on a line) but it gives be a base to work with!

Comment: Yes that was definitely meant to give you something to start with and not a complete solution :)